# How many times per day can users flag questions as "it doesn't belong here"?

Tags: support, flags

Dose every flag reason have its limitation?

In the flag pop up window, we can find the inform moderator flags and spam/offensive flags limitations are 10 and 5 times per day, but the window does not show us the limits of flag as "it doesn't belong here".

Are the "it doesn't belong here" flags limited? If yes, how many times per day can those flags be used?

Comment: [Fabian's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97721/how-many-times-that-users-can-flag-questions-as-it-doesnt-belong-here-per-day/97747#97747) is the right of it for your inquiry, but to address the lack of shown limits on these flags, I think it has to do with being under 3000 reputation. The window shown is actually the close vote selection; users who can vote to close not only get a tally of their remaining close votes, but those flags are automatically converted into close votes for them. I think the lack of displayed limit *might* be because you don't have close votes at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are moderator flags, so it uses the same pool of flags you have for the free-form inform a moderator flag. On the page "it needs ♦ moderator attention" you should see "inform moderator flags remaining" with the number of flags you have left. The exact number depends on your [flag weight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight).

Though it seems somewhat confusing that this number is not shown on that specific page of the flag dialog.

Comment: This is correct - we'll look at putting your remaining flag count on the other popup.